# django: reverse() fails when passing extra options to view function

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling with an annoying error with Django, I'm trying a reverse() passing metadata as a Python dictionary (I'm following the documentation but it does't work, can you help me figure out what I'm missing? )

This is my urlpattern (as you can see I'm passing extra options to my view function, as [described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions)):

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path("items/<int:item_id>", views.item_page, { 'message': None }, name="item page")
]
```

On my views.item_page function I have this:
as

```py
...

reversed_url = reverse("item page", kwargs={'item_id': item_id, 'message': 'hello'} )

return HttpResponseRedirect(reversed_url)
```

I'm getting this kind of error:

```
Django Version:     4.0.4
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    Reverse for 'item page' with keyword arguments '{'item_id': 2, 'message': 'hello'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['items/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']
```

It's like it doesn't accept the "message" argument when reversing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reverse will accept only the arguments those exist in the `urlpattern`
in your pattern there is no `message`
**if you want to send messages **
you can use the `messages` module in django

```py
from django.contrib import messages 

# in View
messages.success(request, 'Hello')
...
```

See the Docs for [Sending messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/)

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning Django and didn't knew about their messages framework. 
I guess my problem was that I was trying to achieve something that `reverse` will not let me do it. I solved by using `messages` this time.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to pass somewhat structured extra information to the next view is to populate its `request.GET` with a [Querydict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects). Something like

```
qd = QueryDict( mutable=True)
qd['whatever'] = 'whatever' # populate it as you wish next view's request.GET to be
...
url = reverse('myapp:wherever', kwargs={ ...} ) # kwargs as defined in urls.py
return HttpResponseRedirect( url + '?' + qd.urlencode() )
```